# Advice on MSA70 Storage and MSA2324fc

Tags: storage-area-network, direct-attached-storage

I am looking into storage for our network, due to budgets am looking at both DAS and SAN solutions but I don't have any experience with HP storage solutions so just got a few questions.

1. On the MSA70, if the server connected to it fails can you connect the MSA70 to a new server with the same type of HBA and gain access to the data again? (With the data being stored in a RAID5)
2. With the MSA2424FC can you reassign a LUN to a different server if the original server fails so that data can be accessed again?

Sorry if these are obvious questions, as you can see I am worried about uptime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to both. For the MSA70, the disks store the raid metadata so the new raid card should pick up the config just fine. For the SAN solution, the new server will see the storage just fine. Problems will come from those associated with moving an entire file system to a new server, if any.